# Terminal inside vim: I can't quit without first exiting the terminal, any autocmd for this?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, autocmd

When I enter vim and open `:terminal` I want to `:wq` or `:q` without first having to switch to the terminal window and typing `exit`

Any autocmds for this? Can't seem to find any.

#### Note:

- I have the terminal to launch in my .vimrc.
- `qa!` etc, doesn't work either, I'll get an error any time I try to quit; 'job running' meaning the terminal.

#### What my vim looks like (for clarity)

[vim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Iridium-Lo/bash/master/Screenshot%202022-09-26%20at%2002.44.56.png)

Comment: doesn't work, says "job running" meaning the terminal

Comment: Try this: `vim --clean "+term" "+qa!"`. It should exit immediately. If it doesn't, then there is a bug in Vim (my v0.9.57 exits immediately). But if it _does_ work, then your vimrc is the culprit, which [you can debug](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file).

Comment: I could have that in my .vimrc as `autocmd vimleave * vim --clean "+term" "+qa!"`, I'll try it, your vim looks ancient, I'm on vim8 :).

Comment: with no .vimrc and just launching terminal I can't get this to work unfortunately

Comment: also tried with a .vimrc with only an autocmd for terminal and the autocmd above you suggested, and yes I sourced .vimrc, also tried on the terminal (outside vim)

Comment: lmao... could it be because I'm on mac? give me a sec I'll test it on my fedora pi

Comment: so that cmd you gave me are you using it as an autocmd? I tried on arm fedora 36 raspberry pi, vim9, with these lines in .vimrc (sourced after): `autocmd vimEnter * terminal` `autocmd vimLeave * vim --clean "+term" "+:qa!` didn't work

Comment: @kadekai I think we are using your cmd in different ways...

Comment: also tried as a single line to no avail

Comment: Why are you using an autocmd? Run `vim --clean "+term" "+qa!"` from your OS terminal emulator, e.g., gnome-terminal, xterm, etc.

Comment: ah ok will get back to you

Comment: this works, much appreciated, can you write it as an answer so I can give credit :)? The only issue is it only works with `:qa!` I tried doing `vim --clean term`<qOptions>` `+:qa`,`+:wqa` ,`+:wqa!` and it ends up entering vim. Thank you I've had this problem for ages and I'm satisfied.

Comment: even without the colons but thanks a lot, this helps so much @kadekai